# How to fix footer at the bottom without position:fixed;?

Tags: html, css

How to fix footer at the bottom without position:fixed;?

I want to fix my footer at the bottom. regardless of content length, how to fix footer? I searched few documents, they usually use min-height on container, and negative margin. I struggled so many time but couldn't find solution, I need your help. Thanks.

Here is HTML Source.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<!-- 기본 JS 파일 로드 -->
<!--%import("./js/global.js")-->
<!--%import("./js/modal_window.js")-->
<!--%import("./js/jquery.blend-min.js")-->

<!--@if($layout_info->display_promotion=='slide')-->
<!--%import("./js/jTypeWriter.js")-->
<!--%import("./js/rotation.js")-->
<!--@end-->

<!--@if($layout_info->display_promotion=='flash')-->
<!--%import("./js/swfobject.js")-->2014-06-24
<!--@end-->

<!-- 기본 CSS 파일 로드 -->
<!--%import("./css/layout.css")-->
<!--%import("./css/option.css")-->
<!--%import("./default.css")-->
<!--%import("./css/slider.css")-->

<!-- PXE Packages CSS 파일 로드 -->
<!--%import("./packages/basic_plugin_pxeSky/accounts.css")-->



<div id="container_site">

<div id="header">

    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="logo"><a href="/index">Logo</a></div>

            <nav>
            <ul class="main">
                <li loop="$main_menu->list=>$key1,$val1"><a href="    {$val1['href']}" class="on"|cond="$val1['selected']" target="_blank"|cond="$val1['open_window']=='Y'">{$val1['link']}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <nav>
            <ul class="accounts">
                    <li cond="!$is_logged"><a href="#" class="login">로그인</a></li>
                <li cond="$is_logged"><a href="{getUrl('act','dispMemberLogout')}">로그아웃</a></li>
                <li cond="!$is_logged"><a href="<!--@if($layout_info->signup_mid)-->{getUrl('act','dispMemberSignUpForm','mid', $layout_info->signup_mid)}<!--@else-->{getUrl('act','dispMemberSignUpForm')}<!--@end-->">회원가입</a></li>
                <li cond="$is_logged"><a href="<!--@if($layout_info->signup_mid)-->{getUrl('act','dispMemberInfo','mid', $layout_info->signup_mid)}<!--@else-->{getUrl('act','dispMemberInfo')}<!--@end-->">마이페이지</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

</div><!--header 끝-->


<div id="container_body">

    <div id="container_contents">   


<div class="left_panel_full">
<div class="left_panel_nav_wrapper">
                    <div class="left_panel_nav">
                    <span style="margin:5px 0 10px 0;"/>Left Title</span>
                       <ul id="lnb" style="border-top:2px solid #000;  padding-top:20px;">
                            <li loop="$side_menu1->list=>$key1,$val1" class="on"|cond="$val1['selected']">
                            <a href="{$val1['href']}" target="_blank"|cond="$val1['open_window']=='Y'">{$val1['link']}</a>
                                <ul cond="$val1['list']">
                                    <li loop="$val1['list']=>$key2,$val2" class="on"|cond="$val2['selected']">
                                    <a href="{$val2['href']}" target="_blank"|cond="$val2['open_window']=='Y'">{$val2['link']}</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
</div>
                <div class="left_panel_nav">
                       <ul id="lnb">
                            <li loop="$side_menu2->list=>$key1,$val1" class="on"|cond="$val1['selected']">
                            <a href="{$val1['href']}" target="_blank"|cond="$val1['open_window']=='Y'">{$val1['link']}</a>
                                <ul cond="$val1['list']">
                                    <li loop="$val1['list']=>$key2,$val2" class="on"|cond="$val2['selected']">
                                    <a href="{$val2['href']}" target="_blank"|cond="$val2['open_window']=='Y'">{$val2['link']}</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
</div>
                <div class="left_panel_nav">
                       <ul id="lnb">
                            <li loop="$side_menu3->list=>$key1,$val1" class="on"|cond="$val1['selected']">
                            <a href="{$val1['href']}" target="_blank"|cond="$val1['open_window']=='Y'">{$val1['link']}</a>
                                <ul cond="$val1['list']">
                                    <li loop="$val1['list']=>$key2,$val2" class="on"|cond="$val2['selected']">
                                    <a href="{$val2['href']}"  target="_blank"|cond="$val2['open_window']=='Y'">{$val2['link']}</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
</div>
                <div class="left_panel_nav">
                       <ul id="lnb">
                            <li loop="$side_menu4->list=>$key1,$val1" class="on"|cond="$val1['selected']">
                            <a href="{$val1['href']}" target="_blank"|cond="$val1['open_window']=='Y'">{$val1['link']}</a>
                                <ul cond="$val1['list']">
                                    <li loop="$val1['list']=>$key2,$val2" class="on"|cond="$val2['selected']">
                                    <a href="{$val2['href']}" target="_blank"|cond="$val2['open_window']=='Y'">{$val2['link']}</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
</div>

</div><!--end of left_panel_nav_wrapper-->
</div><!--end of left_panel_full-->
             <div class="panel_content">
                {$content}
            </div>




    </div><!--container_content 끝-->



</div><!--container_body 끝-->
</div><!--container_site 끝-->
  <div id="footer">
    <ul class="bnav">
        <li loop="$bottom_menu->list=>$key,$val" class="on"|cond="$val['selected']">
                    <a href="{$val['href']}" onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;"|cond="$val['open_window']=='Y'">{$val['link']}</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="hzn">&nbsp;</div>
    <!--<img src="/imgs/css/newinfo.png" class="copyright" />--><span> Footer </span>
</div><!--end of footer-->
```

and Here is CSS...

```
@charset "utf-8";


/* Basic */
html,body { height:100%; margin:0; overflow-y:scroll; }
#container_site { min-height:100%;  margin-bottom:-142px;}

/* Header */
#header { width:100%; height:55px; border-top:4px solid blue;  }
#header .wrap { width:970px; margin:0 auto; position:relative; }
#header .logo { position:absolute; top:17px; left:0; }
#header .main {  position:absolute; top:0px; left:171px; margin:0;       padding:0; list-style: none; border-left:1px solid #e0e2e7; }
#header .main li { position:relative; height:53px;  float:left; margin:0; padding:0; border-right:1px solid #e0e2e7; }
#header .accounts { position:absolute; top:21px; right:15px; margin:0; padding:0; list-style: none; } 
#header .accounts li { float:left; display: inline-block; margin:0 0 0 10px; padding:0 0 0 10px; font:9pt 돋움; letter-spacing:-1px; }
#header .accounts li a { color:#474d56; }
/* #header .more { position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; width:240px;   height:38px; z-index:1000; }
#header .more img { position:absolute; bottom:12px; right:50px; } */


/* Content */
#container_body { width:970px; position:relative;  left:0; margin:0 auto; }
#container_contents { width:970px; border:1px solid #a9afb4; background-color:#f8f9f9; overflow:hidden; min-height:100%;}   
.wrapperTrans { }

.left_panel_full { float:left; min-height:100%;}
.left_panel_nav_wrapper { width:170px; }
.left_panel_nav { margin-left:15px; margin-top:20px; width:137px; border-bottom:1px solid #a9afb4; }
#lnb { list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0; }
#lnb li a { text-decoration:none; color:#000; display:block; height:15px; margin:0; padding:0; margin-bottom:5px; padding-bottom:5px; border-bottom:1px solid #e8e8e8; }
#lnb li ul { list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;  margin-left:0px; }
#lnb li ul li a { text-decoration:none; color:#444; height:15px; padding-left:15px; margin-top:3px; border-bottom:1px solid #eaeaea;}
#lnb li ul li:last-child a { border-bottom:none; }
#lnb li ul .on a { text-decoration:none; color:#347cd5;  height:15px; background:url(imgs/small_on.gif) no-repeat right 7px; padding-left:15px; border-bottom:1px solid #eaeaea;}
.panel_content { float:left; padding:10px 0px 10px 15px; width:780px; border-    left:1px solid #ddd; background-color:#fff;  }



/* Footer */

#footer { position:relative; height:142px; margin:0px; bottom:0; background-color:#454b55; }
#footer .bnav { position:absolute; top:14px; left:22px; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; list-style:none; }
#footer .hzn { width:100%; position:absolute; top:24px;  }
#footer .bnav li { float:left; margin:0 25px 0 0;}
#footer .bnav li a { text-decoration:none; color:#d7d7d7; !important; /*    background:url(/imgs/css/vr_extra.gif) no-repeat left */ }
#footer .copyright { position:absolute; top:48px; left:16px; }

/* Etc */
.block h2 { color:#333; }
```

Comment: If you're talking about fixing it to the bottom of the browser even when the page scrolls, it can't be done just in CSS without `position: fixed` - you'd have to use javascript.

Comment: @CupawnTae No, If the content length is long, the footer should not visible on the screen. scroll down, they will show up. It is Okay

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to avoid `position: fixed;`??

Comment: Please reduce your question to a minimal, self-contained example. No one is going to wade through all that code.

Comment: @JuntaeKim worth mentioning that in the question. Also, you should remove unnecessary code from the question, e.g. all the comments in the HTML.

Answer (score -2):

Please check give position relative to your footer:

```
'http://jsfiddle.net/p4r5asqr/1/'
```

Comment: The footer *has* `position:relative` in the question